# Finding $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2^{n/2}\Gamma({\frac{n}{2}})}\int_{n+\sqrt{2n}}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{t}{2}}t^{\frac{n}{2}-1} dt$

Tags: limits, probability-distributions

Find

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[\frac{1}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}\Gamma({\frac{n}{2}})}\int_{n+\sqrt{2n}}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{t}{2}}t^{\frac{n}{2}-1} dt\right] $$

After looking at it for a while i found out it(the value in brackets) is similar to  [$\chi^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) variate integrating over interval (as specified in the question) so solving the brackets $$P[t\ge n+\sqrt{2n}]=1-P[t<n+\sqrt{2n}]$$ now if we take limit of the above equality $$\lim_{n\to \infty}1-P[t<n+\sqrt{2n}]=1-P[t<\infty]=0$$ now please tell me where am I wrong and what might be the correct solutuion for it(i don't have the value) and this is not a homework problem.

Comment: Your reasoning is clever but flawed. Your $\chi$-squared distribution has $n$ degrees of freedom, but $n$ is increasing in the limit. So you are effectively computing the tail cumulative distribution of a random variable $\chi_n$,  $P[\chi_n\geq n+\sqrt{n}]$, but your random variable is not the same for every $n$. You cannot consider it fixed, as you did in the reasoning before. For a full solution of the limit, see below.

Comment: If $T\sim \chi^2_n$, then the limit in question is indeed $$\lim_{n\to\infty}P(T>n+\sqrt{2n})=\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(\frac{T-n}{\sqrt{2n}}>1\right)$$

Since $T$ is distributed as $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^2$ where $(X_i)$ is an i.i.d sequence of $N(0,1)$ variables, by the classical CLT

$$P\left(\frac{T-n}{\sqrt{2n}}>1\right)\longrightarrow 1-\Phi(1)\approx 0.15865$$

Answer (score 0):

Change integration variable $t=(n+\sqrt{2n})z$ and get
$$
I(n)=\frac{1}{2^{n/2}\Gamma(n/2)}(n+\sqrt{2n})^{n/2}\int_1^\infty dz e^{-(n+\sqrt{2n})z/2}e^{(n/2)\log z}/z\ .
$$Rewriting the integral in a form suitable for Laplace's approximation, we get
$$
I(n)=\frac{1}{2^{n/2}\Gamma(n/2)}(n+\sqrt{2n})^{n/2}\int_1^\infty \frac{dz}{z}e^{-n [z/2-\log(z)/2]}e^{-\sqrt{2n}\ z/2}\ .
$$
The integral is heavily dominated by the region around $1$. So expanding the exponent around $z=1$ and retaining terms up to up to the second order, we get
$$
I(n)\approx\frac{1}{2^{n/2}\Gamma(n/2)}(n+\sqrt{2n})^{n/2}e^{-n/2}\int_1^\infty dz\ e^{-n(z-1)^2/4}\frac{e^{-\sqrt{2n}\ z/2}}{z}
$$
$$
\approx\frac{1}{2^{n/2}\Gamma(n/2)}(n+\sqrt{2n})^{n/2}e^{-n/2}e^{-\sqrt{2n}/2}\int_0^\infty dz\ e^{-n z^2/4}\frac{e^{-\sqrt{2n}\ z/2}}{z+1}\ .
$$
Replacing $z+1$ with $z$ in the denominator (as the region around $z=0$ is now the most relevant), we eventually obtain
$$
I(n)\approx\frac{1}{2^{n/2}\Gamma(n/2)}(n+\sqrt{2n})^{n/2}e^{-n/2}e^{-\sqrt{2n}/2}\frac{\sqrt{e \pi }\ \text{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}\to \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{erfc}(1/\sqrt{2})\approx 0.158655.. 
$$
which is the value of the original limit (erfc is the complementary Error function). It can be verified numerically in Mathematica or WA as

ListPlot[Table[{n, 
   NIntegrate[
    1/(2^(n/2) Gamma[n/2]) Exp[-t/2] t^(n/2 - 1), {t, n + Sqrt[2 n], 
     Infinity}]}, {n, 20, 150000, 5000}], 
 GridLines -> {{}, {(1/2) Erfc[1/Sqrt[2]]}}, 
 PlotRange -> {0.158635, 0.158659}, AxesLabel -> {"n", "I(n)"}]